# Fetching all parents in simple way with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, recursive-query

I have a table with a hierarchical structure:

```
    _________
    |Plans   |_____________________________________________
    |-------------------------------------------------------|
    | id     | parent | plan_name      | description        |
    |-------------------------------------------------------|
    | 1        0        Painting        bla..bla            |
    | 2        1        Shopping        bla..bla            |
    | 3        1        Scheduling      bla..bla            |
    | 4        2        Costumes        bla..bla            |
    | 5        2        Tools           bla..bla            |
    | 6        2        Paints          bla..bla            | 
    |_______________________________________________________|
```

I want to list all parents of the plan name `Paints`, so I can build a breadcrumb to navigate back. Using `id = 6` I like to get:

```
Painting > Shopping > Paints
```

I'm using postgresql with PHP, and thinking of efficient way to fetch all the parents as simple as possible.

Comment: "Paints" is a task/plan name in table Plans, so you can call it anyway

Comment: @wingedpanther Painting is the top level parent, then shopping, final child is Paints, so I want to list the 2 parent names/records, so I can frame this way- everything from same table

Comment: Adjacency lists are a bit of a pain to work with, they're simple to create but a right faff to query. I suggest reading [this](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) which provides examples of using the adjacency list structure, but also highlights a possibly better solution - the nested set model.

Comment: @wingedpanther Ah so it is, my bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [recursive with query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive pl(id, parent, parents) as (
    select id, parent, array[parent]
    from plans
union
    select pl.id, plans.parent, pl.parents|| plans.parent
    from pl
    join plans on pl.parent = plans.id
    )
select distinct on (id) id, parents
from pl
order by id, array_length(parents, 1) desc

 id | parents
----+---------
  1 | {0}
  2 | {1,0}
  3 | {1,0}
  4 | {2,1,0}
  5 | {2,1,0}
  6 | {2,1,0}
(6 rows)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a5b2/1)

Instead of integer array of parent ids you can use text column to aggregate plan names:

```
with recursive pl(id, parent, parents, depth) as (
    select id, parent, plan_name, 0
    from plans
union
    select pl.id, plans.parent, plans.plan_name|| ' > ' ||pl.parents, depth+ 1
    from pl
    join plans on pl.parent = plans.id
    )
select distinct on (id) id, parents
from pl
order by id, depth desc;

 id |            parents
----+--------------------------------
  1 | Painting
  2 | Painting > Shopping
  3 | Painting > Scheduling
  4 | Painting > Shopping > Costumes
  5 | Painting > Shopping > Tools
  6 | Painting > Shopping > Paints
(6 rows)
```

Comment: thanks, can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652930/count-of-students-in-each-class-while-listing-class-names-using-postgresql ?

Comment: This query takes ~25ms for me. Is there way to increase performance?

Comment: `id` should be the primary key. The index on `parent` can also be helpful but you won't see differences on such a small example. Also note, recursive queries are by their nature rather expensive.