# count of students in each class while listing class names

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables,

`classes`
 `students`

every student record will have a mapping record (lets say `class_id`) in `students` table, so that maps which student belongs to which class, now I want to list all class records along with the count of students associated with that class.

suggestions/solutions please.

Im sure a solution is available for this, I tried with my search skills but no luck, any existing question/answer would be a quick and great help.

Comment: you should post your attempt instead of asking for a solution

Comment: Have you considered reviewing your lecture notes and textbook?  Hint: there is a standard aggregate function named `COUNT()` that can help.

Comment: Of course there's a solution, but we're not here to *provide* code, we're here to *help* you with *your* code. Do some research, try out, and if it's not working, come ask about a **specific** problem.

Comment: thanks @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup (see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c67a5/1)):

```
create table classes (class_id int primary key, class_name text);
create table students (student_id int primary key, class_id int references classes);
insert into classes
select i, 'Class'|| i
from generate_series (1, 5) i;

insert into students
select i, floor(random()* 5+ 1)::int
from generate_series (1, 20) i;
```

Use `count()` on joined table:

```
select class_id, class_name, count(student_id)
from classes c
join students s using(class_id)
group by 1, 2
order by 1
```

Comment: thanks @klin, you are great :)

Comment: I tried the same for joining another table, say teachers, so each class row should fetch total count of students from students table and teachers count from teachers table, but the counts are not really working fine, it is returning same value for both counts,any help please

Comment: You cannot do that in one-level query, must use a subquery, see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56dd6/2)

Comment: Note - I have added `left` to `join` in case there are no teachers (students) joined to one of the classes (like in the example).